# What is the difference between nvidia-graphics-drivers and nvidia-graphics-drivers-updates

Tags: nvidia, package-management

I see that there are two packages nvidia-current and nvidia-current-updates. The apparently stem from nvidia-graphics-drivers and nvidia-graphics-drivers-updates respectively:

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-updates

I wonder why there are two packages, and what is the difference between these two packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first package is the binary driver that will stay the same version until next ubuntu release. The second driver is the binary driver that will have updates before next ubuntu release.

You can decide which one you want to use by running jockey.

Comment: How did you find this information? Does Ubuntu have any naming guidelines? And what is "jockey"?

Comment: @dan3 This is a bit late but I found the answer to what "jockey" is (or was!) at http://askubuntu.com/a/441418/340383