# What has Jockey been replaced with in 14.04?

Tags: jockey, 14.04

Just tried to run `jockey-text` on my test server and found that it's not installed. Looked for the `jockey-common` package and found nothing. Even did [a package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jockey&searchon=names&section=all) and there's no release for Trusty.

I feel like I've missed an important bit of news but what manages the "additional drivers" side of things in 14.04? Has Jockey been replaced or just renamed?

Comment: @Oli I know that you are the OP, but how this isn't relevant to 14.10 and up?

Comment: @Braiam It is but this is new in 14.04 and my question is about 14.04 (hence the tag). Most pointedly, it's what *I'd* search for (hence the title). In 6 months time, feel free to rename it to "since 14.04" :)

Comment: Sorry, but that's not how tags are supposed to work. Tags are for categories, not for descriptions and are not supposed to "summarize your question using the tags" but to make "specific categories". In this case this question is not relevant to only 14.04 hence there's no need for the tag. I would consider it if it was hardware question, but it isn't. I'm not going to go back and fix something I could fix right now.

Comment: Thanks for keeping 14.04 in there Oli.  I assume that it is common for tags to mark the first of a string of releases that a question is relevant for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-drivers-common
```

*ubuntu-drivers-common* detects and installs additional Ubuntu driver packages.

This package aggregates and abstracts Ubuntu specific logic and knowledge about third-party driver packages, and provides APIs for installers and driver configuration GUIs. It also contains some NVidia specific support code to findvthe most appropriate driver version (as Ubuntu usually ships several), as well as setting up the alternatives symlinks that the proprietary NVidia and FGLRX packages use.

### Command line interface

The simplest front-end is the "ubuntu-drivers" command line tool. You can use it to show the available driver packages which apply to the current system (`ubuntu-drivers list`), or to install all drivers which are appropriate for automatic installation (`sudo ubuntu-drivers install`), which is mostly useful for integration into installers.

See also: [Can I install extra drivers via the command prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22118/can-i-install-extra-drivers-via-the-command-prompt)

Comment: Will this just install **all** available drivers without user confirmation/selection (e.g. hypothetical case when I need a WiFi driver but dont want a graphic driver)?

Comment: @Takkat I added the reply to your comment to my answer.

Comment: Thank you... *ubuntu-drivers* appears to have no manpage available in the whole of the Internets O.o

Comment: @Takkat Yeah that's pretty bad form. `ubuntu-drivers --help` is some use but it doesn't seem to explain everything.

Answer (score 8):

`jockey` has been superseded by `software-properties` in Ubuntu 14.04. Hence forth, `software-properties` would handle third-party driver configuration.

Sources: [launchpad jockey-gtk amd64](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/jockey-gtk) and [launchpad jockey-gtk i386](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/i386/jockey-gtk/0.9.7-0ubuntu15).

`software-properties-common` available here [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/software-properties-common) and others available [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=software-properties&searchon=names).

Comment: Superseded, not replaced. It's a small big difference.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I think they are both the same.

Comment: @AdityaPatil there is a difference: 'superseeded' means you can still use the old one. 'replaced' means the old one is gone ;-)

Comment: So which is it? Superseded or replaced?

Comment: The LP bit you cite conflicts with your answer. `software-properties` hasn't replaced anything (recently), `ubuntu-drivers-common` has. `software-properties-common` contains scripts like `add-apt-repository` and (until recently) `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: @oli probably software-properties uses ubuntu-drivers-common. I will try to cite this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to launch from the command line to see additional output, launch `software-properties-gtk`.